# How to Use AsyncStorage in react native expo cli functional component

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, expo, asyncstorage

I am trying to use Async Storage in react native expo cli to use login credentials even after closing the app. I am using firebase otp authentication as a mode of login. I am struck here to use the previously used phone number and otp. Below is my code.

This is one screen where user will enter mobile number.

```ts
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react'
import { Alert, View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeBaseProvider, Text, Image, Button, Input } from 'native-base';
import { Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from "react-native-easy-grid";
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import styles from '../styles/styles';
import firebase, {phoneAuthProvider} from '../firebase';
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from 'expo-firebase-recaptcha';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const DummyWelcome = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
    const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);
    const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);

    const sendVerification = async () => {
        try {    
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('phoneNumber', phoneNumber) 
        } 
        catch (erorr) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Storing phone Number') ;
        phoneAuthProvider
        .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier.current)
        .then((id) => {
            //   console.log('verification:',id);
              setVerificationId(id);
              navigation.navigate("DumOtp", {verificationId: id})
          });  
      };

    return (
       <NativeBaseProvider>
           <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
      ref={recaptchaVerifier}
      firebaseConfig={firebase.app().options} />
           <Grid >
           <LinearGradient
            colors={['#64B278', '#03621B']}
            style={styles.linearStyle}/>

            <Row size={40}
            style={styles.containerRow}>
                <Image 
                source={{uri: 'https://d2j6dbq0eux0bg.cloudfront.net/images/30049435/1646525107.jpg'}}
                alt="Subhiksha Logo"
                width= {150}
                height={150}/>
            </Row>

            <Row size={5}
            style={styles.textStyle}> 
                <Text 
                style={styles.welcomeText}>Welcome</Text>
            </Row>

            <Row size={5}
            style={styles.textStyle}> 
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.phoneText}>Enter your phone number to contine</Text>
            </View>
            </Row>

            <Row size={10}
            style={styles.justifyCenter}>
                <Input 
                style={styles.inputText}                
                placeholder="Enter your phone Number"
                placeholderTextColor= "white"
                onChangeText={text => setPhoneNumber(text)}
                maxLength={13}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'/>
            </Row>

            <Row size={20}
            style={styles.justifyCenter}>

            <Pressable
            style={styles.pressableStyle}
            onPress={sendVerification}>
                
             {/* onPress = {() =>  */}
             {/* text.length < 10 ? Alert.alert("Invalid Submission", "Please Enter 10 digit Mobile Number to continue") : navigation.navigate("DumOtp")}> */}
                <Text 
                style={styles.pressableTextStyle}>Generate OTP</Text>
            </Pressable>
            </Row>
            
           </Grid>
       </NativeBaseProvider>
    )
}

export default DummyWelcome
```

This is another screen where otp will be auto captured.

```ts
import React,{ useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { NativeBaseProvider, Image, View, Pressable, Text, Button } from 'native-base'
import { Col, Row, Grid } from "react-native-easy-grid";
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import OTPInputView from '@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input'
import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard'
import styles from '../styles/styles';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import firebase from '../firebase';
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from 'expo-firebase-recaptcha';

const DummyOtp = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60);
    const [code, setCode] = useState('');
    // const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);
    const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);
    const {verificationId} = route.params;
    // console.log(code)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (seconds > 0) {
          setTimeout(() => setSeconds(seconds - 1), 1000);
        } else {
          setSeconds('OTP Expired!');
        }
      });

      const confirmCode = async () => {
        try {    
             const dataa = await AsyncStorage.getItem('phoneNumber');
             if(dataa!== null){
              const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                verificationId,
                code
              );
              firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithCredential(credential)
                .then((result) => {
                
                // console.log(result);
                navigation.navigate("DumQuestion1");
                });
             }
        } 
        catch (error) {   
            console.log(error)
        } 
      }

    return (
         <NativeBaseProvider>
           {/* <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
      ref={recaptchaVerifier}
      firebaseConfig={firebase.app().options}/> */}
      
          <Grid >
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['#64B278', '#03621B']}
            style={styles.linearStyle}
            />

             <Row size={30}
            style={styles.justifyCenter}>
                <Image 
                source={{uri: 'https://d2j6dbq0eux0bg.cloudfront.net/images/30049435/1646525107.jpg'}}
                alt="Subhiksha Logo"
                width= {150}
                height={150}
                />
            </Row>

            <Row size={5}
            style={styles.textStyle}> 
                <Text 
                style={styles.welcomeText}>Welcome</Text>
            </Row>

            <Row size={5}
            style={styles.textStyle}> 
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.phoneText}>Enter one time password to contine</Text>
            </View>
            </Row>

            <Row size={10}
            style={styles.otpRow}>

            <OTPInputView
              style={styles.otpStyles}
              pinCount={6}
              autoFocusOnLoad
              codeInputFieldStyle={styles.codeInputFieldStyle}
              codeInputHighlightStyle={styles.codeInputHighlightStyle}
              onChangeText={text => setCode(text)}
              onCodeFilled = {(code => {
                setCode(code);
              })}
              />
              </Row>

            <Row size={10}
            style={styles.centerContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.otpTimerText}>{seconds}</Text>
            </Row>

            <Row size={10}
            style={styles.centerContainer}>
              <Text underline style={styles.otpNotRecieved}>Didn't receive OTP?</Text>
              <Text style={styles.resendText}> Resend</Text>
            </Row>

            <Row size={15}
             style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 10}}>

            <Pressable
            style={styles.pressableStyle}
            onPress={confirmCode}>
              <Text 
              style={styles.pressableTextStyle}>Authenticate</Text>
              </Pressable>
            </Row>

            {/* <Row size={15}
             style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 10}}>

            <Pressable
            style={styles.pressableStyle}
            onPress={() => console.log(verificationId)}>
              <Text 
              style={styles.pressableTextStyle}>Login</Text>
              </Pressable>
            </Row> */}
           </Grid>
       </NativeBaseProvider>
    )
}

export default DummyOtp;
```

Comment: What did you try that's not working and what error message/wrong behavior do you get. Don't just say you're stuck.

Comment: I have tried storing the credentials that are required to login, but getting this error.
**Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occured**.

Comment: Do you get that error when you call `AsyncStorage.getItem()` or `AsyncStorage.setItem()` or both?

Comment: I am getting this error while calling ```AsyncStorage.getItem()``` itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.